# How to use raise ValueError?

Tags: python, valueerror, raise

I want to see `ValueError` `4` times but it is showing once, why the program cutting to search the other double numbers?

```
def isitDoubleorSingle(value):
    if(value%2!=0):
        raise ValueError("Number isn't double")
    print(value)    

list=[10,22,79,43,11,80]

for x in list:
    isitDoubleorSingle(x)
```

Comment: once you ```raise``` an error, the program stops running. do you want a [warning](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html) instead? Also, you shouldn't redefine the built-in ```list```

Comment: Aside, can be simplified to `if(value % 2)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will solve your problem. You have to catch your Error in the except block or your script will stop running at your first `raise ValueError()`

edit: As @Nin17 said, you shouldn't redefine the built-in list, so renaming the list in my_list(or any name you want) should be better.

```
def isitDoubleorSingle(value):
    try:
        if(value%2!=0):
            raise ValueError()
    except ValueError:
            print(f"Number {value} isn't double")

my_list=[10,22,79,43,11,80]

for x in my_list:
    isitDoubleorSingle(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you raise an exception, the program is already closed automatically, so it is not possible to display the ValueError more than once